# How to reduce the width of Primefaces <p:menubar>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to reduce the width of the `<p:menubar>` in primefaces. By default, it covers the whole screen with but I want to reduce that. I've tried using css "`width: 70%;`" but still not working. Does anyone knows the way out?

Comment: have you tried to set as !important? `width: 70% !important;`

Comment: Oh that works perfect. Thanks @Pellizon. 
Can I ask on more question on menubar?
How can I evenly distribute submenus such that if there are just 5 submenus, they would be evenly positioned on the bar instead of all starting from the left. Probably a space between them or a submenu center alignment.
Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try to set the `margin` style of each `p:submenu`

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried this `margin-right: 10px !important;` and it's manageable. Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome! Remember that using `!important` is not a good practice... The recommended should be understand the CSS layers and modify the root. The use of `!important` can give you a little headache after a while

Answer (score 1):

Give you menubar an exclusive class (lets say **my-70-pc-menu**) to avoid every manubar to be 70% and than change your css file to place this:

```
.my-70-pc-menu{
    width: 70% !important;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Daniel but what difference does the `.ui-menubar` in your above css code makes? My css doesnt have that but still works after adding `!important` to it. Do you have a suggestion or answer to my comment above about distributing `submenu` or `menuitem` on the menubar?

Comment: My bad! That was just my old habits. I will update the answer.